# Macro Benchmarks for Java

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking

I'm looking for Java applications and appropriate (macro) benchmarks for them. For instance, I already use PolePosition to benchmark the performance of HyperSQL. Benchmarks based on JBench, JUnitBenchmarks, and similiar tools are also possible. I'm not looking for benchmarks for the JVM!

Comment: Why do you want to benchamrk random applications? Or is there some specific task that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Generally, I want to analyze the performance influence of certain bytecode manipulations on large scale.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is being here for some time already, but for the future viewers:

you may consider

- http://hdrhistogram.org/
- https://github.com/OpenHFT/JLBH

I bet everybody has listened about [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), but usually, it is not a good option for **macro** benchmarks (for **micro** benchmarks it's the best)